# plot an overlay of data with different frequency

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have dataframe A like:

```
Date        index
Jan-2000    1.11
Feb-2000.   1.22
Mar-2000.   1.33
..............
Jan-2019.   1.13
```

Also, dataframe B like:

```
Date.          index
01-01-2000.    1.01
02-01-2000.    1.00
.........
01-02-2000.    1.21
.......
31-01-2010.    1.11
```

dataframe A is what I got from Internet and b is from my prediction and you can see A and B have different frequency.

I have ploted them seperately and find that they have nearly the same shape. What I want to do is to plot them in the same pic to compare my prediction but the frequency is not the same. Is there a method I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, just plot your two frames in the same plot using your dates on the x-axis. `matplotlib` figures out the correct spacing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random(3), columns=['a'],  
                    index=pd.date_range(date(2000, 1, 1), periods=3, freq='Y'))
df_b = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random(24),  columns=['b'],  
                    index=pd.date_range(date(2000, 6, 1), periods=24, freq='M'))

plt.plot(df_a.index, df_a['a'])
plt.plot(df_b.index, df_b['b'])
```

[image]